# Can not update "OneToMany" children

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have got a problem with updating entity.

Each User can be in one Group only.

Schema for user is:

- id INT
- username STRING
- group_id INT DEFAULT NULL

Schema for group is:

- id INT
- name STRING

**Group.php**

```
class Group {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Saprizo\Entity\User", mappedBy="group", cascade={"all"})
     */
    protected $users;

    public function setUsers($users) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $user->setGroup($this);
        }
        $this->users = $users;
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SaprizoStatistics\Entity\Group", inversedBy="users", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $group;


}
```

When I try to add new users to group like

```
$group->setUsers(array($user1, $user2));
$em->persist($group);
$em->flush();
```

it save all values.

But when I try to delete all users from group like

```
$group->setUsers(array());
$em->persist($group);
$em->flush();
```

it do nothing. As I understand after setting an empty array and saving it group_id column for user1 and user2 should change to `null`.

Is it mistake in Doctrine annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your setUsers function you will notice that when you pass an emtpy array, (as you do when trying to remove all the users) the foreach loop is simply skipped and the group_id of the user entity is maintained.

Although mbinette's answer is correct I would suggest making a separte function for removing the users. With mbinette's suggestion, when adding new users, you would have to add all the users in the array, since you remove them all first.

```
public function removeUsers() {
    foreach ($this->users as $user) {
        $user->setGroup(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a mistake in Doctrine's annotation. You're never removing the old users from the group. You'll need to remove them manually once you've added them to a group. Just change your `setUsers()` method.

```php
public function setUsers($users) {
    //Remove old users first
    foreach ($this->users as $user) {
        $user->setGroup(null);
    }
    //Now we can add the new ones and replace the array
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user->setGroup($this);
    }
    $this->users = $users;
}
```